# Removing layers from a pretrained keras model gives the same output as original model

Tags: keras, keras-layer, keras-2

During some feature extraction experiments, I noticed that the 'model.pop()' functionality is not working as expected. For a pretrained model like vgg16, after using 'model.pop()' , model.summary() shows that the layer has been removed (expected 4096 features), however on passing an image through the new model, it results in the same number of features (1000) as the original model. No matter how many layers are removed including a completely empty model, it generates the same output. Looking for your guidance on what might be the issue.

```
#Passing an image through the full vgg16 model
model = VGG16(weights = 'imagenet', include_top = True, input_shape = (224,224,3))
img = image.load_img( 'cat.jpg', target_size=(224,224) )
img = image.img_to_array( img )
img = np.expand_dims( img, axis=0 )
img = preprocess_input( img )
features = model.predict( img )
features = features.flatten()
print(len(features)) #Expected 1000 features corresponding to 1000 imagenet classes
```

1000

```
model.layers.pop()
img = image.load_img( 'cat.jpg', target_size=(224,224) )
img = image.img_to_array( img )
img = np.expand_dims( img, axis=0 )
img = preprocess_input( img )
features2 = model.predict( img )
features2 = features2.flatten()
print(len(features2)) #Expected 4096 features, but still getting 1000. Why?
#No matter how many layers are removed, the output is still 1000
```

**1000**

Thank you!

See full code here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/files/1592641/bug-feature-extraction.pdf

Answer (score 10):

Working off @Koul answer.

I believe you don't need to use the `pop` method.  Instead just pass the layer before the output layer as the argument for the `Model` method's output parameter:

```
from keras.models import Model

model2 = Model(model.input, model.layers[-2].output)
model2.summary()
```

Comment: As pre-trained keras models at current time (TensorFlow 2.4.0) use functional (not sequential) models, which do not support the `.pop()` method, this is the only solution that works.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer here : https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2371#issuecomment-308604552

```
from keras.models import Model

model.layers.pop()
model2 = Model(model.input, model.layers[-1].output)
model2.summary()
```

model2 behaves correctly.

Comment: At time of writing with most recent TensorFlow (2.4.0), this method does not work as using `.pop()` on a functional model raises an error. However, user3731622's answer below still works.